# Hex string to ASCII conversion with errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, ascii

I am trying to write a python script to convert a hex string into ASCII and save the result into a file in .der cert format.  I can do this in Notepad++ using the conversion plugin, but I would like to find a way to do this conversion in a python script from command line, either by invoking the notepad++ NppConverter plugin or using python modules.

I am part way there, but my conversion is not identical to the ASCII ouptut seen in notepad++, below is a snippet of the output in Notepad++

[image]

But my python conversion is displaying a slightly different output below

[image]

As you can see my script causes missing characters in the output, and if i'm honest I don't know why certain blocks are outlined in black.  But these missing blocks are needed in the same format to the first picture.

Here's my basic code, I am working in Python 3, I am using the backslashreplace error control as this is the only way I can get the problematic hex to appear in the output file

```
result = bytearray.fromhex('380c2fd6172cd06d1f30').decode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')

text_file = open("C:\Output.der", "w")
text_file.write(result)
text_file.close()
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an input example?

Comment: Those black characters look like the ones which are non-ASCII characters (or are ASCII control-codes). Here's a [chart](http://www.cpptutor.com/imgs/ascii_table.gif),

Comment: I have adjusted the original question to include the hex string for the given output pictures, thanks.

Comment: @martineau, agreed that was my initial understanding, but I guess it's more around the format, if I can get notepad++ to display a python script output in the same way it does using it's plugin, then I am confident the cert file generated will work.

Comment: When I run your code I get an output file containing the hex bytes `38 0C 2F 5C 78 64 36 17 2C 5C 78 64 30 6D 1F 30`. What do want the output to be? I don't care what it looks like in some text editor, like notepad++ or any other—just exactly what you want in the file. The two `5C 78` substrings each represent `\x` prefixes, by-the-way.

Comment: @martineau, it's difficult to say, it's to generate a .der cert file so I guess it's never meant to be opened in a text editor, so i can't give an accurate answer.  From my output I am nearly there, I just need the extra backslashes removed from the output (maybe your output with 5C 78 removed would work?), ironically I generate the backslashes using the backslashreplace error control, but this is the only way I can get the text to appear in the output to match the Notepad++ output (which I know works) - sorry that's probably not much help

Comment: Is making the `.der` output file contain exactly the byte values represented in hex by the `'380c2fd6172cd06d1f30'` string the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MikG, I would say that python did exactly what you requested.

You told to convert the bytes to string, and replace bytes with most significant bit set with escape sequence (except for \xFF char).

Characters \x04 (ETB) and \x1F (US) are perfectly legal ASCII chars (though non-printable), and they are encoded using their literal value.

Characters \xd6 and \xd0 are illegal in ASCII - they are 8-bit long. They are encoded using 4-letter long escape sequence, as you asked: "\" (backslash char) and "xd6" / "xd0" strings

I'm not good with DER, but suppose that you expect to have raw 8-bit sequences. Here is how this could be accomplished:

```
result = bytearray.fromhex('380c2fd6172cd06d1f30')

with open("Output.der", "wb") as text_file:
    text_file.write(result)
```

Please note "wb" specifier to `open` -- it tells python to do binary IO.

I also used [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement to ensure that `text_file` is closed whatever happens with write.

Comment: So close! it's almost there with your solution, I am now just missing the NUL blocks (similar to the black blocks in the diagrams), instead I get a blank space in the output when opened in Notepad++.  NUL can be added by adding 00 in the original hex string.

Comment: @MikG I don't have any problems with NUL characters.

Comment: @MikG it is the feature of a text editor that you use to view the DER file. It reads up to the first NUL char. Use a hex editor instead. Or simply check  the size of the output file. I tried in Linux python 3.6 - it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @PakUula you are correct, the NUL entries are there.  I copy and pasted the output to the same text editor window as the Notepad++ generated conversion to do a visual comparison and the NUL entries got omitted on pasting for some reason, but they are there in the file created from your script, many thanks for your help.